# Random.nextInt() is returning the same number

Tags: java, android

My code is below, I have tried using the Random class and the Math.Random() method. It works fine on the first call, however when I try and replay the Random guessing game after clicking the "Try Again" button in the app, the same number is returned.

The Try Again Button calls TryAgain()

```
package com.example.austin.higherorlower;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int randNumber;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button tryAgain = findViewById(R.id.tryAgainButton);
        randNumber = returnRand();
    }

    public int returnRand(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randInt = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
        Button tryAgain = findViewById(R.id.tryAgainButton);
        tryAgain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return randInt;
    }

    public void GuessRandom(View view) {

        EditText numberGuessedEdit = findViewById(R.id.guessedRandomValue);
        String numberGuessedString = numberGuessedEdit.getText().toString();
        int numberGuessed = Integer.parseInt(numberGuessedString);
        if (numberGuessed < randNumber) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Higher", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(numberGuessed > randNumber) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lower", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(numberGuessed == randNumber){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct! Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button tryAgain = findViewById(R.id.tryAgainButton);
            tryAgain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void TryAgain(View view){
        returnRand();
    }
}
```

Comment: TryAgain() doesn't appear to do anything with the int returned. It completely ignores it

Comment: Do not create a new `Random` on each call. Make it a field, and instantiate it once; e.g., `private Random rand = new Random();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `Random` here, recreating a `Random` in a loop is going to pick the same *seed* and that will make it not random at all. Luckily, there is [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) which you can use as a drop in replacement. Like,

```
int randInt = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(20) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just importing the Math class and calling `Math.random()`? That returns a float between 0.0 and 1.0,and you can use `Math.floor(20*Math.random()) +1` to get a random number (it will be a whole number saved as a float) between 1 and 20.

Answer (score 0):

if you're having trouble with the Random class I advise you to use the Math class.
I found a nice function that can help you.

```
int myRand(int i_from, int i_to) {
    return (int)(Math.random() * (Math.abs(i_from - i_to) + 1)) + Math.min(i_from, i_to);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with using a Random object; however Elliott Frisch might be right that somehow simply constructing the Random in a no-arg constructor might be using the same seed over and over again.  All I know is, that's not how it works in the Java world (see the javadocs on Random, which are pretty thorough), but as you're working in Android all bets are off.

you might try tweaking it a couple of different ways.  You could either:

1. Declare Random an instance variable rather than a method declaration.  That way, subsequent calls to rand.nextInt will be in a common Random context and not starting over with the exact same seed again (if that is indeed the problem).
2. Instantiate Random using the seeded constructor.  A good seed to use here would be System.currentTimeMillis() because that will be guaranteed to be different from moment to moment.
3. Do both 1 and 2.